# Preventing hyphenation for words containing numbers

Tags: hyphenation

I have a word containing a number, "MyVeryBigWord1", that I never want hyphenated in my document. Here's a file replicates the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\hyphenation{MyVeryBigWord1} % ERROR: Not a letter.

\usepackage[a4paper, total={1mm, 8in}]{geometry} % make tiny paper area

\begin{document}
some-otherword
MyVeryBigWord1 MyVeryBigWord1 MyVeryBigWord1
\end{document}
```

If I comment in the `\hyphenation` this toy document builds (with an error) and looks fine but the document I'm actually writing it doesn't build properly with the error. How do I prevent the error and make it so my word is never hyphenated?

Comment: `\newcommand{\MVBW}{\mbox{MyVeryBigWord1}}` in the preamble and `\MVBW{}` in the document.

Comment: Have you tried `\hyphenation{MyVeryBigWord}`? (TeX won't hyphenate between "MyVeryBigWord" and "1".) Alternatively, assuming the real word -- it's *not* really "MyVeryBigWord1", right? -- doesn't occur very often in your document, have you considered encasing all instances in an `\mbox` wrapper?

Comment: I ended up going with this `mbox` idea. I don't know why I didn't try it earlier. The end result: `\newcommand*{\dataset}[1]{\mbox{\textit{#1}}}` used `\dataset{MyDataSet1}`. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can make 1 a letter for hyphenation purposes, if you really need it

```
\documentclass{article}

\lccode`1=`1
\hyphenation{MyVeryBigWord1} % ERROR: Not a letter. (it is now)

\usepackage[a4paper, total={1mm, 8in}]{geometry} % make tiny paper area

\begin{document}
some-otherword
MyVeryBigWord1 MyVeryBigWord1 MyVeryBigWord1
\end{document}
```

Comment: Clever. I ended up going with an `mbox` implementation as my I was already using a macro tat made `mbox`. But I appreciate the help. I gave you an upvote :)